# Inverse of the product of non-square, full-rank matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, pseudoinverse

I have a matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{m \times m}$ defined as:
$$
M^{-1} = P^T A P
$$
Where $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}, P \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times m}, n > m$ and both $A$ and $P$ are full rank. Also, $P^T P = I_m$ where $I_m$ is the identity matrix of size $m \times m$. Is there any way to express $M$ in terms of $A^{-1}$? Maybe using the psudoinverse of $P$ or something?

Comment: If we add columns so that $U = [P \ Q]$ is an orthogonal matrix, then we can write
$$
U^TAU = \pmatrix{P^TAP & P^TAQ\\Q^TAP & Q^TAQ} = \pmatrix{M^{-1} & B\\C & D}
$$
Knowing $A^{-1}$ is equivalent to knowing the inverse of the full matrix 
$$
U^TAU = \pmatrix{M^{-1} & B\\C & D},
$$
so your question really amounts to whether we can deduce the inverse of a submatrix using the inverse of the full matrix.  I believe that the answer to this is no (i.e. we won't have a formula in terms of $A^{-1}$).